# Theming LaTeX documents

Tags: templates

I would like to create LaTeX documents with new visual styles that use color, fonts, and header style that differ from the standard Computer Modern style everybody knows.

I have been doing my academic work exclusively in LaTeX for a long time now, but I have resisted for using LaTeX for anything else because black-and-white Computer Modern texts scream *academia*. While it is easy to switch article classes, and doing so is well documented, this does not seem to be the case with themes. A Google search easily found me themes for LaTeX slideshow classes, but not for regular articles.

What options are there for creating document 'themes' in LaTeX, or where might existing theme collections be found?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: It's not very difficult to modify document looks.  Here's an example of how to emulate MSWord :-) [Change Section Fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10138/2693); you may not want that particular scheme, but the general idea is the same. Using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX allows you to use any font installed on your system.

Comment: Maybe someone could implement a LaTeX theming system.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get a document in a look far from arcticle-class and Computer Modern is to load the `scrartcl` class from the KOMA-script bundle and to use e.g. the libertine package for the fonts. Give it a try.

The english manual of KOMA-script is not really up-to-date, but everthing described there still works as desribed. In case you'd like to have more features, just ask here, tex.stackexchange is visited by many Germans who will give you a hand.

Regards,

Alexander

Answer (score 1):

They are no *themes*, but you can look at [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/1952), and you will find a big amount of examples of *not-so-standard-latex-looking* documents. Some of them show their sources so you can easily reproduce (or adapt to your needs) them.

Answer (score 1):

Most packages change the layout in some way. Many packages have only the purpose to change the layout or provide possibilites to do so. However it would not help you to have a list of several hundret packages that you could use.

It may help you to look at the examples for theming in my latex templates. Though I do apply only little changes, since it is supposed to be used by academic users. You find the old version on my website http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/latex/vorlagen/allgemein/#toc-koma-script-version-3-x and the current development with many changes and more current approaches here http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/latextemplate/scmsvn/?action=AccessInfo.

If you have something special in mind it would be necessary to get to know your design ideas.