# Make a LaTeX document look like it was written in Microsoft Word

Tags: fonts, formatting, margins, line-spacing, msword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a LaTeX document appear as though it were typeset in MS Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39544/making-a-latex-document-appear-as-though-it-were-typeset-in-ms-word)

I know this is a travesty in the world of TeX, and an affront to all decent TeX-believing people out there...

But the graders for one of my research papers insist that it be written with 12pt Times New Roman font, 1-inch margins, double-spaced (the Microsoft Word defaults).  Is there a template I can use for LaTeX to fulfill these specifications?

(This is the exact opposite of [Make MS Word document look like it has been typeset in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8308/9757).)

Comment: Use `hyperref` package with all the possible conflicting packages and probably it will look just like MS Word. :P

Comment: I'm very happy you understand that it's a travesty. Just to reassure you, I didn't vote to close because of the "travesty", but just because there actually *is* a duplicate. Keep up the good fight, give your graders two versions - the Microsoft Woad version and some real typography. See if you can get him to lose sleep over keming.

Comment: Those aren't the Microsoft Word defaults.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this al least in two ways; using the [wordlike](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wordlike) package:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{margin=1in}{geometry}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{wordlike}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

or, without `wordlike`, you can use something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

The [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package lets you customize the page layout.

The [setspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package allows you to achieve double spacing.

The lines

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
```

give you the combination Times/Helvetica/Courier.