# LyX Hyphenation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx, hyphenation

In LyX I want my paragraphs to be justified, without the use of hyphenation. I am using `\exhyphenpenalty=10000\hyphenpenalty=10000` in my preamble and it works, but I notice that the first line of the first page of text extends about 0.5cm past the right alignment. Is this a problem with the code? Or, is there better code to deal with this?

Comment: why would you ever want that? No typeset work would ever justify without hyphenating, the only possible choice then is to have unreadably large inter-word spaces. You will need to issue the command `\sloppy` to allow inter-word spaces to stretch that much.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am trying to recreate the justify that is seen in most word processing applications. The above code makes the document look perfectly find, save the first line problem referenced in my question.

Comment: @ChrisJ Then `\sloppy` should be the answer. There are other questions about the same problem. For instance http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39544/making-a-latex-document-appear-as-though-it-were-typeset-in-ms-word

Comment: So I guessed, but why buy a Ferrari and ask how to make it work like a go-cart?

Answer (score 2):

"first line of the first page of text extends about 0.5cm past the right alignment"

I suspect you get this precisely because you try to avoid hyphenation. You probably need to manually induce hyphenation for that first line, specifically by doing `Insert > Formatting > Hyphenation Point`. See Section 5.6 of [Essentials of LyX](http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/LyX/tutorials/essentials/LyX_Essentials.pdf).