# How do I set the document body to be Times New Roman and Section headings to be Arial?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change section fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10138/change-section-fonts)

for a University Assignment I have been given some 'House Style' rules which must be adhered for all the documentation. These are:

**Main Text Body:** Times New Roman, 12pt

**Heading 1:** Arial, 16pt

**Heading 2:** Arial, 14pt

**Heading 3:** Arial, 12pt

I know that I need to use XeLaTeX in order to use system fonts, however, no matter what I try, I cannot get the document to display correctly.

Any idea on how I would implement this is Tex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you already tried to create a preamble? What class are you using? You will need [`fontspec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) and its macros `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont`.

Comment: You do **not** need XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX: You can use one of the type1 equivalents or just install the package [`winfonts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/winfonts) (the ttf versions have to be installed for this).

Answer (score 5):

Modifying the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10138/2693) to the sizes you need, this should be quite straightforward:

```
% Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
% Set sans serif font to Arial
\setsansfont{Arial}
% Set serifed font to Times New Roman
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
% Set formats for each heading level
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{16}{18}\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\fontsize{12}{14}\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
This is some text.
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]