# Using multiple system fonts

Tags: fonts, fontsize, fontspec

I'd like to use 3-4 different specific system fonts (e.g., Georgia, HelveticaNeui Light, and Lucida Sans) with certain font sizes for different sections of a page. How would I do this?

Edit: Thanks for the responses. I saw the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package but the examples I found defined in the preamble `\setmainfont{}`, `\setsansfont{}`, etc. I couldn't figure out how to define a fontfamily and then reference it for a particular section. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\section{Georgia}%here define font

This text shows in Georgia.

\section{Lucida Sans}%

This text shows in Lucida Sans

\section{HelveticaNeue Light}%here define font

This text shows in Helvetica Neue Light

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Have you looked into the `\newfontfamily` directive of the `fontspec` package?

Comment: Here's an example of pretty much exactly what you want to do: [Change section fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10139/2693).

Comment: Thanks, Alan. I saw that example which defines the formatting by section, subsection, etc. I'm looking to specify formatting for different sections - I'm used to styling in HTML/CSS where to do this you'd assign each paragraph to different classes and then for each of those classes define the font size, font family, color, margin, etc.

Comment: @Jack The principle is the same. You can define various section-like headings using `titlesec`.  I'll post an example shortly. But reading your question more carefully, I'm wondering, do you want the text *within* a section to be of a different font, or the section heading, or both?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you just want chunks of text to be a different font you can simply set up environments for them using whatever semantics makes sense for your document. The main thing to remember is that you should use `\newfontfamily` to define a font switching command for each font rather than using the `\fontspec` command directly. For example:

```
% Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\newfontfamily\calibrifont{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\cambriafont{Cambria}
\newfontfamily\georgiafont{Georgia}

\newenvironment{calibri}{\calibrifont}{\par}
\newenvironment{cambria}{\cambriafont}{\par}
\newenvironment{georgia}{\georgiafont}{\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{calibri}
This text is in Calibri
\end{calibri}
\begin{cambria}
This text is in Cambria
\end{cambria}
\begin{georgia}
This text is in Georgia
\end{georgia}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: What happens if you use `pdflatex`?

Comment: @MarioS.E. You don't. `fontspec` requires either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.