# Journal Paper Specs

Tags: fonts

I use the `titlesec` package to adjust the section/subsection and font issue:

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt]{article}      % Use this line for a4


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries\sffamily\filcenter}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
  {\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
  {\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {1em}
  {}

\begin{document}
\section{Section one}
\subsection{Subsection one}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one}
\end{document}
```

How to change this to achieve:

sections : times new roman, hang, bold 12pt

subsections : times new roman, hang, italic 12pt

Comment: Your journal should have templates. Use them.

Comment: Have you tried google/search? Anyway look in these places: http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/schmidt/schmidt.pdf, chapter 4 "How can I change the fonts to be used for certain parts of the document?" this question might be actually helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877597/how-do-you-change-the-document-font-in-latex or this one:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10139/19326 In short, I suggest you try to google some and then ask about the ones you actually have trouble with.

Comment: You are asking several questions at once (about sectioning headings, the title, and headers). I suggest that you confine this question to one topic (e.g. about sectioning headings, as done in your "answer") and ask new questions (including proper minimal examples) for other issues.

Comment: You should tell us which documentclass you are using.

Answer (score 5):

It is actually really simple. All you have to do is to follow the clear tutorial available here : [Layout tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to change:

1. the `\sffamily` commands should be removed from those title formats where they are not relevant.  `\sffamily` switiches to sans serif
2. to get italics, add `\itshape` to the format for subsection

Here is your example with these changes and each style made `hang`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt]{article}      % Use this line for a4

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\itshape}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
  {\normalfont\normalsize}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {1em}
  {}

\begin{document}
\section{Section one}
\subsection{Subsection one}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one}
\end{document}
```

`\bfseries` is producing the bold fonts.  The specification `\fontsize{12}{15}` tells LaTeX to choose a font of size `12pt` and set the baselineskip (the space from the base one line to the base of the next line) to `15pt`.

See `fntguide` [`texdoc fntguide`] for definitions of the font changing commands and the documentation of `titlesec` [`texdoc titlesec`] for further formatting commands for the titles.

Spacing around titles is specified using a different command.  E.g.

```
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*4}{*1.5}
```

means that sections are

- left indented `0pt`
- have space `4ex` (four times the height an x) before them
- and space `1.5ex` after them

Actually the spacings are not 100%, but have some stretchability, to allow LaTeX to fit material in to pages nicely.  If do not want that variablity then you can write

```
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{4ex}{1.5ex}
```

or use other units such as

```
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{20pt}{8pt}
```

although I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the function of {15}. I hope it be the spacing after the heading?( since i want to set this spacing to 6)

Comment: Explanation added.