# Write a title in blue color

Tags: sectioning, color, templates, cv

```
\section{Publications}

\begin{twentyshort}%
\twentyitemshort{1865}{Chapter One, Down the Rabbit hole.}
%\twentyitemshort{<dates>}{<title/description>}
\end{twentyshort}
```

This code has been taken from Overleaf working based on online. I would like to write the **Publications** in blue color. What should I do?

Comment: Just this one section, or all `\section`s? If the latter, see if e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10138/change-section-fonts helps.

Comment: Would you like to explain after which line I should write {xcolor}? And when I will name the color?

Comment: Which template is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\usepackage{color}
...
\begin{document}
...
\section{\color{blue}Publications}
```

or

```
\section{\textcolor{blue}{Publications}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am really grateful to you. Would you like to say what is the function of "twentyshort" or "twentyitemshort"? I am afraid to ask you one more suggestion. If I want to write "Chapter One, Down the Rabbit Hole" in bold, what should I do?

Comment: Twenty seconds template is for CV documents only. There is no use in making it have chapters.

Comment: I don't know what "twentyshort" or "twentyitemshort" is. That is something you have written, not I.

Comment: Sorry for my question. Yes, you didn't write "twenty short". I think, I should make another post to know what I should do if I want write "1865, chapter one, down the rabbit hole" in bold, don't I?

Comment: Well, usually chapter titles are in bold in LaTeX, using the \chapter command.